# How to specify polymorphic association with custom primary keys in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a few ActiveRecord classes using [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/) for version tracking. The AR classes have custom primary keys based on their table names (e.g. `Item.ItemID` instead of `Item.id`) in order to adhere to business DB conventions.

paper_trail specifies a polymorphic relationship on each of the tracked classes, thus:

```
class TrackedExample < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name 'TrackedExample'
    set_primary_key 'TrackedExampleID'

    # simplified from https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/has_paper_trail.rb
    has_many :versions
        :class_name => 'Version'
        :as         => :item,
end

class AnotherTrackedExample
    set_table_name 'AnotherTrackedExample'
    set_primary_key 'AnotherTrackedExampleID'

    has_many :versions
        :class_name => 'Version'
        :as         => :item,
end

# from https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/version.rb
class Version
    belongs_to :item, :polymorphic => true
    ...
 end
```

If I were not using custom primary keys, the version object could refer to the tracked object (i.e. the object of which it is a version) using `Version#item`. When I try it, I get an error:

```
# This should give back `my_tracked_example`
my_tracked_example.version.first.item

=> TinyTds::Error: Invalid column name 'id'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) [TrackedExample].* FROM [TrackedExample] WHERE [TrackedExample].[id] = 1 ORDER BY TrackedExample.TrackedExampleID ASC'
```

Is there a way to get Version#item to perform the correct query? I would expect something like this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) [TrackedExample].* FROM [TrackedExample] WHERE [TrackedExample].[TrackedExampleID] = 1 ORDER BY TrackedExample.TrackedExampleID ASC'
```

I'm using Rails 3.1.0, paper_trail 2.6.4 and MS SQL Server through TinyTDS and [activerecord-sqlserver-adapter](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter).

**EDIT:** I've worked around the problem by adding computed columns `TrackedExample.id` and `AnotherTrackedExample.id` that refer to the primary key values. This isn't a proper solution (Rails is still making the wrong query), but it may be useful to others in a hurry.

MS SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE TrackedExample
    ADD COLUMN id AS TrackedExampleID
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than specifying `t.references :item`, `polymorphic: true` in your migration file.
You simply have to specify the `item_id` and `item_type` as follows:

```
t.string :item_id

t.string :item_type
```

Rails will automatically select the correct `primary_key` for the `item_id` and correct type.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this might work

```
class Version
  belongs_to :item, :polymorphic => true, :primary_key => 'TrackedExampleID'
  ...
end
```

Comment: That would work OK if all the tracked classes had the same primary key. My problem is that they're all different, and I don't know how to tell the Version class about that (if it's even possible).

Edited the example to make the situation clearer.

Comment: Looking through the rails source I think your original code should work as-is. It looks like ActiveRecord is asking for the primary key of the polymorphic parent if you don't set one. I wouldn't expect a difference, but try using self.primary_key= instead of set_primary_key?

Comment: Using `self.primary_key=` made no difference, as expected. But thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: I've verified that your original code works correctly in Rails 3.2 with MySQL. I don't have MS SQL or Rails 3.1 to test against, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

After scouring the PaperTrail documents it doesn't look like you can override what column `item_id` references (i.e. the primary key of the Item's table), so I think you have two main options:

**1. Create an `id` column that does not have the name of the class in it. So, `id` instead of `TrackedExampleID`.**

You said you already did this as a quick fix.

**2. Fork and patch PaperTrail to allow you to pass what column to use when querying for `item_id`.**

This could either be the value set with `set_primary_key 'TrackedExampleID'` or it could be something set like `has_paper_trail primary_key: 'TrakedExampleID'`.

Let us know what you end up with.